# PHPUnit Path issue

Tags: ubuntu, phpunit

I installed PHPUnit 3.6.10 recently.

I don't understand what is wrong with the include_path in php.ini file

the php.ini files being used are as follows

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini
```

another file being used by Apache2 is `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

I have changed the include paths both in `cli/php.ini` and `apache2/php.ini`

the include path which I wrote in php.ini is

```
include_path = ".:/home/username/pear/share/pear:/usr/share/php
```

previously the include path was

include_path = .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear

but the error form PHPUnit is this way

```
    PHP Warning:  require_once(PHPUnit/Framework.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/username/public_html/PHP-Library/APITest.php on line 14
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Framework.php' (include_path='.:/home/username/pear/share/pear') in /home/username/public_html/PHP-Library/APITest.php on line 14
```

This is written in the APITest.php file

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';
```

Could anybody explain what the problem is? Is there any other place where I need to make changes in php.ini?

**Update**

when I run below command

```
$ php -c /path/to/php.ini -r 'echo get_include_path()."\n";'
.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear
```

**update 2**
When I remove require and extend PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase I get the following error
in apache2 logs I found

```
[Sun Mar 11 14:54:58 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in /home/username/public_html/phplib/APITest.php on line 15
```

Comment: Oh, you're trying to run PHPUnit from within Apache? Can you post that code you're using to start the test runner? Look at `/usr/bin/phpunit` and [`phpunit.php`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.6/phpunit.php) to see what the standard script does.

Comment: The command line is now some how working fine. But when running from browser I get http 500 error.

Comment: Specifically, how are you running it from the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPUnit 3.6 has its own autoloader that is responsible for making all of the classes available without using `require`. Simply extend the test case in your tests without worrying about PHPUnit.

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase { ... }
```

**Update**

When running your tests through the browser, you're bypassing the `phpunit` executable which sets up the autoloader. Add

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
```

to your `index.php` script (or whatever runs the tests).

Answer (score 0):

I had to add in the following to my php.ini: /usr/share/php/

The entire string looks like this in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:

```
".:/usr/bin/php:/var/www/cakephp2/lib/:/var/www/cakephp2/:/usr/bin/phpunit:/usr/bin/pear:/usr/share/php/"
```

To figure out where to link it I ran

```
locate Autoload.php
```

From the shell which pointed me to where PHPUnit was installed at /usr/share/php/PHPUnit and then looking at what it was trying to include I concluded I needed to add /usr/share/php